# When assigning a static array to a non-static array in C#, is it done by reference or value?

Tags: c#, reference, static, non-static

My question is one about C# language behaviour. I have code where I have a few static arrays with different values and a non-static field array which is being set to one of these arrays at a different time. My assumption is that if UpdateArrayToUse below was called, it would set it by reference, meaning that if LoadArrays was called again at a later time with the disk values having changed then the non-static field Options would have already changed. However, this isn't the behaviour I'm seeing. I'm curious to know if anybody has any insight into this.

```
    private static string[] StaticArray1;
    private static string[] StaticArray2;

    public static void LoadArrays()
    {
        //Loads arrays from disk, can be changed elsewhere
        StaticArray1 = LoadArray1();
        StaticArray2 = LoadArray2(); 
    }

    public void UpdateArrayToUse(int i)
    {
        if(i == 1){
            Options = StaticArray1;
            return;
        }

        Options = StaticArray2;
    }

    public string[] Options;
```

Comment: None of the three arrays in your code are non-static, although your question implies there should be one?

Comment: Damn, yeah, that was a typo when I was approximating the real code for the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `LoadArray` doesn’t change any arrays. It assigns what the methods return, which apparently are new ones and you assign them to the variables. Therefore if you store a reference to a previous array somewhere it will still retain its value.

It would be different if the arrays were already created and you changed the values in them. Then what you expected to see would happen.

But we don’t know exactly what the code inside those loading methods does. It *could* also use an internal array that isn’t allocated again, in which case again it would be different.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks. _Options_ is just storing a reference to what used to be in the static array, rather than a reference to that field. Seems obvious now!